# Please help wade through the meta tag [tips-and-tricks]

Tags: support, retag-request

The tag [tips-and-tricks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) (x33) really feels like a meta tag to me, you can't ask a single question about it and a question that would be polling for tips and tricks is off topic anyway.

Can people help go through the tag checking if we can improve / close / delete / preserve  the questions?

*See [random's answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/4510/9666) below for details...*

Comment: Most of these are "not constructive" while some you could cherry pick some parts for the blog.

Comment: @random: Yeah, not a bad idea. I actually saw this tag on the example blog question you gave me and wasn't sure if you were inspecting the tag, so posted it here to be sure. I wonder though if there is an easy way to copy all the links (without having to do that manually) such that we can always access them...

Comment: I'd also note a good chunk of them seem closed - so those arn't a big issue either. Any issue with creating seperate answers with questions that are closed, open ended (and thus closable) and could survive sans the tag, but fit the site, and editing them? Might be a neater way than having monolitic answers to handle it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek They'll rather be converted to blog posts or pushed into Tag Wikis.

Comment: I mean, for immediate sorting, not long term post management - i ended up doing what i did instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, went through it, and there's several sorts of questions and posts..

## keep - questions that seem to fit SU, and have a clear aim

> Improve if possible

[What files and/or directories can be removed from a Windows XP install without breaking anything?](https://superuser.com/questions/195622/what-files-and-or-directories-can-be-removed-from-a-windows-xp-install-without-b)

[Make an OS X Installer Think that it is on Snow Leopard, not Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/151997/make-an-os-x-installer-think-that-it-is-on-snow-leopard-not-leopard)

[Tomato QoS: Why is some traffic unclassified when there are classifications for it?](https://superuser.com/questions/84179/tomato-qos-why-is-some-traffic-unclassified-when-there-are-classifications-for)

[How best to copy an SD card with corrupt filesystem to attempt recovery?](https://superuser.com/questions/144588/how-best-to-copy-an-sd-card-with-corrupt-filesystem-to-attempt-recovery)

[Emacs check syntax of file before saving](https://superuser.com/questions/116402/emacs-check-syntax-of-file-before-saving)

https://superuser.com/questions/21065/tips-to-prepare-your-computer-for-a-clean-windows-install

[How to have a timer driven "reload" of a tab in Mac OS X Safari 4?](https://superuser.com/questions/19605/how-to-have-a-timer-driven-reload-of-a-tab-in-mac-os-x-safari-4)

---

Comment: Removed some that were deleted now.

Comment: @slhck: And which one go to the blog? Or should I wade through the earlier revision?

Comment: @TomWijsman I already added ideas to the Trello. Feel free to browse through earlier revisions if you find some more stuff worth blogging about.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the slower approach on this.

Go through the list of questions tagged with it and run the following checks:

1. Find a way to edit the question to be constructive, more direct. E.g. "what are your tips?" into "How can this be done?", "What keyboard shortcut do I need to execute?", etc. Remove the tag as you do.
2. If the first check fails, vote to close as not constructive.

Additionally, for those that you have voted to close, think about whether or not any of that content would be good for the Super User blog. It may, it may not.

And then the tag will be cleaned up naturally when there are no more live questions tagged with such after they are deleted. Say, in a week's time?

Comment: Good idea about moving stuff to the blog